How to add global OpenVPN configuration on Ubuntu for all users
I can find 1001 sites describing how to configure OpenVPN for an Ubuntu user. However, I'm looking to understand if there is a way as an administrator to add a configuration once that's available to all users on the machine.
I have an LDAP+Kerberos server and my router/firewall is configured as an OpenVPN server with SSL/TLS + user authentication. I intend to create machine-specific keys and certificates signed by my root CA. When I export the .ovpn client settings from the firewall they include the machine-specific private key and public certificate which I then import on the client machine.
It sounds better as an administrator to install the private key and public certificate on the machine, therefore hiding the key behind /etc/ssl/private and not need to distribute the sensitive information in the .ovpn files. And as a bonus, each network-authenticated user that logs in does not need to (and can't) import the OpenVPN configuration themselves.
I haven't been able to find a setup described in this way, if it's possible, let alone how to do it. Can someone indicate if this is doable and, if so, how?
In case it makes any difference, this would be for Ubuntu 24.04.
